# How do I validate that a screen name does not have any symbols or spaces with regex?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, validation, ruby-on-rails-3.1

How would you validate a screen name using regex (on Ruby on Rails)?

I'm looking for a bit of regex to validate (in an RoR model) that a screen name does not have any symbols or spaces in it.

Comment: What counts as a symbol?  Are diacritic considered symbols?

Comment: `/\S+/` is the most common solution

Comment: Sorrym got confused, it should have been `/^\w+$/`

Comment: @I82Much In my case that would be any character other than an underscore, letter, or number. David Grayson hit the nail on the head for what I was looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you want to specify a blacklist of characters that aren't allowed, but there are a lot of characters out there that you probably don't want in screen names so it would be better to use a whitelist.  Here's an example that would only allow letters, numbers, and underscores in screen names and restrict the length to be 2-30:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_format_of :screen_name, :with => /\A[a-zA-Z0-9_]{2,30}\Z/
end
```

Comment: I like this solution, I should have know to use a whitelist!

Answer (score 0):

```
if string =~ /^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/
  # name is valid
else
  # name is not valid
```

I believe that will work :)

Comment: Prolly it will, but using Rails helpers (validates...) is much better idea ;)